# Code Sign EXE - Does it include the detailed address of my company in the signature?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, code-signing, codesign, code-signing-certificate

As I can see, in Windows, the Digital Signature tab of an EXE file will show the Company Name, City Name, and Country Name of the company.

Is the user able to find the detailed address of the company from the signature? The situation is the same for OV and EV code signings?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information appearing on the Digital Signature tab come from the 'Subject' field of the certificate.

This information is provided by the company when signing keys are generated.
Then, those keys are used to generate a [Certificate signing request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request) (CSR) who contains this information + public key.
This is this CSR who is transmitted to the certificate authority.

The certificate authority will then sign digitally the certificate with his proper key, after validation of information present on the CSR. It will not add any further information about the company, only validate and sign. The validation process of the company by the authority will be different for OV or EV, but information present on the certificate stays those provided by the company on the CSR.

The detailed address of the company will appear only if it was provided when signing keys were generated.

This is not typical information required on a certificate, but the company can choose to add personalized information on the Subject field.
I am not aware of any certificate authority who require the detailed address on CSR.

Comment: So, can the end users find out my detailed address via the certificate authority?

Comment: It is unlikely that the certificate authority provide this kind of information to an individual end user who ask for it. Maybe you can ask directly to your certificate authority to be sure? Nevertheless, it is always possible for the certificate authority to be hacked one day, or to be forced to give information to national authorities.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so as it would not be very secure to display the company's detailed information. This could lead to someone breaking in or harassing workers where Microsoft could be blamed as they let the company's address go public.

Comment: I want to be certain about this.

Answer (score 0):

[image: screenshot]

Data about an exe file made with visual studio is created like this inside the AssemblyInfo.cs (in C# projects) in the properties. This is all the data that can be found if I'm correct. Every application made in visual studio will have something like this, I'm not sure about C++ projects, but it should be something around the lines like this.

Comment: This is not something I am asking. I am asking the OV and EV Certs.